# Sequence/series divergence proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

Suppose $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence (for $n \geq 1$) that diverges and let $s_n = |x_{n+1} - x_n|$. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} s_n$ diverges.

My attempt:

Let us use a contrapositive argument:

Assume that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} s_n$ converges. This shows that $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n = 0$. By the definition of limits, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that for $n \geq N$, we have $|s_n| < \epsilon \implies |x_{n+1} - x_n| < \epsilon$.

We need to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$ for some $x$. So for all $\epsilon_2 > 0$ we need to find some $N_2$ such that for all $n \geq N_2$, we have $|x_n - x| < \epsilon_2$.

(What I thought to do at this point: Because $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} (x_n + 1)$ by change of index we can let $\epsilon =$ something?)

Notice that

$||x_{n+1}| - |x_n|| \leq |x_{n+1} - x_n| < \epsilon$ - the reverse triangle inqlty

Not too sure what to do from here and I'm hoping that somebody can point me in the right direction. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall this theorem: every absolutely convergent series is convergent. We are going to use it in the proof.

Suppose that $\sum_n s_n$ converges, then the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (x_{n+1} - x_n)$$
is absolutely convergent. In particular, it is convergent to some real number $A$. This is a telescoping series, and for all $N$ you have
$$\sum_{n=1}^N (x_{n+1} - x_n) = x_{N+1}-x_1$$
Indeed
$$x_{N+1} -x_1= (x_{N+1} - x_N ) + (x_{N} - x_{N-1} ) + (x_{N-1} - x_{N-2} ) + \cdots +(x_2-x_1)$$
If you take the limit of the RHS you get a real number
$$A = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N (x_{n+1} - x_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (x_{n+1} - x_n)$$
Hence $\{ x_N\}$ converges to $A+x_1$: in particular it is convergent, and this completes the proof.

Comment: How can you conclude that $\{x_n\}$ is convergent from that?

Comment: $$\lim_{N \to \infty} x_N = x_1+  \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (x_{n+1} - x_n) = x_1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_{n+1} - x_n) $$ which is convergent.

Comment: Sorry... I am new to analysis. How did you come up with this equation?

Comment: Actually nevermind. I think I have understood.